# flask python update operation

Tags: python, mongodb, crud

I update collection in mongo db . but cant find matches. this is my code.

```
 collection = MongoClient()["blog"]["users"]
 client = MongoClient()
 db = client.blog
 result = db.test.update_many({"_id": '12345'}, {"$set": {"email":    
 "dmitry"}})
 print (result.matched_count)
```

Comment: I mean matches exist , but update doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the _id field which is immutable, you will need to create a new entry and delete the old one by storing the document into a variable and then saving it with the new _id and then removing the old document.

Comment: I changed for another version . it is also doesn't work